# Upgrading FontAwesome from 3.2.1 to 4.x

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm upgrading FontAwesome from 3.2 to 4.1. What would be the least painful way to do it since there is significant difference in syntax of both versions (https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4).

My current two options are:

- Searching in HTML for `icon-` and replacing with `fa-` (Returns thousands of results!)
- Editing FontAwesome 4.x CSS and changing prefixes to `icon-*` (Since i'm not using any other lib with `icon-` prefix - Easier but what about future versions?)
- Any other way?

Comment: You pretty much answered your question. If you change the CSS file, it won't work with future versions of FA (unless you also change those CSS files), or you change the classes in your markup. I'd go with the search&replace the markup, it will take more time but you'll know that you won't have to change the CSS file every time the newer version of FA comes out.

Comment: I think search and replace is the way to go, but i was hoping for a more elegant solution where i might change fa- prefix in the fontawsome css for backward compatibility. There should be prefix independent code like the idea here : https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer.

Answer (score 1):

Any text editor will allow you to replace all occurrences of `icon-` into `fa fa-`.

It will take you less than 30 seconds, and you'll be ready for future Font Awesome updates.

- Sublime Text: <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd>
- Eclipse: <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>
- Notepad: <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>
- Notepad++: <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>
- NetBeans: <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+H</kbd>
- ...

Remember to check for [new icon names](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Upgrading-from-3.2.1-to-4#new-icon-names) (you should know which one you're using, so I guess you don't have to check for all icons).